# visual studio add in to get information of the project and pass it to existing c# program and display results in views

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am from Java backgroud and have very little knowledge about `.net`. We have a application written in `c#` that scans source code files and calculate various things like code metrics defect density and different type of defects in the code and such and returns xml files with all the values. What I am trying to do is create a add in (I belive add in is something like plugin for eclipse) that will get the paths of the source code and pass it to the methods in the current c# code of the tool and get the result values and display them as a table with tree strucutre in a view. How can I get this done in Visual Studio using c#? Help me out. The add in is trageted for VS 2010 ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can do it as an AddIn or an Extension. You should get yourself the [VS SDK](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680&ei=3y8_UJSfMOaO4gTjuICICg&usg=AFQjCNFomfqr0oRI089zvgO871w_eRM9zQ&sig2=y0FJfDao3JTOWE1abtamTA) and start by creating simple things. There are a lot of namespaces and classes dealing with the things you mentioned so the beginning learning curve is pretty hard. Inside those AddIns or Extensions you are absolutely free in displaying data, triggering when your tool should run etc.

Comment: Thanks spinter, so should i develop it as an add in or an extension what advantages i get by making it an extension rather than an add in?

Comment: The "new" way would be the Extension-way. I would suggest you that one. It uses new paradigms and I guess it is the future. Some advantages are the deeper and more free integration in VS, modern techniques. But at some points the technologies are equal. To hold it short: Use extensions. By the way: Extensions can be deployed and offered via Visual Studio Gallery very nicely!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now i am in a state where i need to convince leadership to go with Extension and telling its new alone is not gonna help. I would like to know weather there are things i can do more with extensions that i cant with an addin? From what i googled around, finding guides for add in developemnt is easier that for extensions. As far as i did reaearch i was not able to find a way how i can add a menu item when i right click on a project file in solution explorer using add-in, is this thing possible with extensions?

Comment: Lets see: Extensions are better integratable into the IDE (menus, toolbars), you can use WPF instead of windows forms, they can be deployed without dealing with folders (vsix-format), they can perform auto-updating. Probably there are some more arguments but this should do the job.